# How to active/deactive a shipping method by code

Tags: shipping-methods

I would like to schedule the shipping methods `activation/deactivation` programmatically.

I've created job correctly but I don't know how to load the shipping method object to call (if it exists) `->setData('is_active', $status)` and to save it, as for cms block.

**CMS Block Example:**

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blocks_to_active[$row])->setData('is_active', $status)->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. It was easier than I thought.

The shipping methods status is saved in `core_config_data` table (`where path like 'carriers%active'`); so I don't need to load a "shipping method" object.
Just use `Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig()` Magento function.

In my case:

#### For Activation

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('carriers/my_shipping_method/active', 1, 'default', 0);
```

#### For Deactivation

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('carriers/my_shipping_method/active', 0, 'default', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is close, thank you. But selecting `carriers%active` gets you the carrier's *active/inactive* state, not each method.

**UPS** for example, has many methods (ups_01, ups_03...), which is what I was looking for and I thought your original question was asking that.

I was looking to target specific methods within a particular carrier. But you are right, the `core_config` is the place to do it.

The `carriers/%/allowed_methods` configuration values provide a comma-delimited list of allowed methods per carrier, if enabled. In this case, one would need to know the method codes beforehand to update this configuration value as needed. But you steered me in the right direction, so it saved me looking elsewhere. Nice.

Glad you figured out your own needs.

Comment: I'm happy to read your comment and to know my answer helped you.
If you want, you could click on "_This answer is useful_" (upvote) button to help another people.